# css isn't acting the way I want it to across multiple browsers

Tags: css

( I have this in a jsfiddle site that can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TechGuyAlabama/aHkKC/). )

Here is what is happening in Internet Explorer:

[image]

This is how I want it to look and ironically, IE is doing what I wanted.

When I view this in Chrome or Firefox, this is what is happening:

[image]

As you can see, it's not split down the center.

Here is what my razor page looks like:

```
@using System.Collections
@using SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService
@model SuburbanCustPortal.SuburbanService.CustomerData      

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Account Screen";
 }

<h2>AccountScreen</h2>

<div class="leftdiv">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Customer Info</legend>
    @Html.Partial("CustomerInfo", Model)
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Delivery Address</legend>
    @Html.Partial("DeliveryAddress", Model)
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Delivery Info</legend>
    @Html.Partial("DeliveryInfo", Model)
  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <fieldset> 
    <legend>Balance</legend>
      @Html.Partial("AccountBalance", Model)
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Account Options</legend>
    <br/>

     @using (Html.BeginForm("AccountScreenButton", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      <div class="sidebysidebuttons">
        <div class="box">
          <button name="options" value="payment">Make a Payment</button>
          &nbsp;
          <button name="options" value="activity">Display Activity</button>
        </div>
      </div>      
    }

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset> 
      <legend>Billing Info</legend>
        @Html.Partial("BillingInfo", Model)
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And this is in my css file that I'm calling:

```
.leftdiv {
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
}
.rightdiv {
    float: right;
    width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
    display: inline;
}
.sidebysidebuttons {
 float: left;
 display: block;
  margin-left: 60px;  
text-align:center   
}
```

Anyone know how I can get them to look the same, or rather both like how IE is displaying them or see what I'm doing wrong?

===== as requested =====

This is the page source when the page has loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Your Company Name Here : Account Screen</title>
  <link href="/Content/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/web.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Views/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.focus :input').focus();
        });
    </script>

</head>
    <body>

        <div class="page">

            <div id="header">
                <div id="headerimg"></div>  
                <div id="logindisplay">
                        Welcome <strong>webtest</strong>!
    [ <a href="/Account/LogOff">Log Off</a> ]

                </div>
                <div id="menucontainer">
                    <ul id="menu">

               <li><a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com">Home</a></li>

                          <li><a href="/Customer/AccountScreen">Account</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/Payment/PrePayment">Make Payment</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/GasOrder/OrderGas">Order Gas</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/Home/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                          <li><a href="/Account/UpdateAccount">Update Login</a></li>

                          <li><a href="/Home/NewsList">* Sales *</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="main">


<h2>AccountScreen</h2>

<div class="leftdiv">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Customer Info</legend>

<div  class="leftdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Account Number:</label>            
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Name:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Mailing Address:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">City:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">St/Zip:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Phone Number:</label>
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">01 - 02228&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">PICKERING VALLEY CONTRAC&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">960 POTTSTOWN PIKE&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">CHESTER SPRINGS&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">PA&nbsp;&nbsp;19425&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">610&nbsp;458-7200</label>
</div>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Delivery Address</legend>

<div  class="leftdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Care of:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Delivery Street:</label>            
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Delivery City:</label>  
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">&nbsp;</label>  
</div>

  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Delivery Info</legend>

<div  class="leftdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Last Delivery Date:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Number of Tanks:</label>            
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Tank Serial#:</label>  
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Tank Size:</label> 
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Tank Type:</label> 
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Qty Last Delivered:</label> 
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Year To Date Deliveries:</label> 
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Year To Date Gas:</label> 
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Total Used Last Year:</label> 
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">10/16/2012&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">1&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">30&nbsp;</label>

      <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel"> &nbsp;</label>

  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">15&nbsp;</label>  
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">4&nbsp;</label>  
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">70.4&nbsp;</label>  
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel">117.0&nbsp;</label>  
</div>


  </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <fieldset> 
    <legend>Balance</legend>
    <div>

<div class="leftdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 30:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 60:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 90:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Over 120:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Current:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Total:</label>
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$7.15&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$90.48&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$5.50&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$37.31&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$7.34&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightLabelRed">$147.78&nbsp;</label>
</div>

    </div>    
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Account Options</legend>
    <br/>

<form action="/Customer/AccountScreenButton" method="post">      <div class="sidebysidebuttons">
        <div class="box">
          <button name="options" value="payment">Make a Payment</button>
          &nbsp;
          <button name="options" value="activity">Display Activity</button>
        </div>
      </div>      
</form>
  </fieldset>

    <fieldset> 
      <legend>Billing Info</legend>
      <div>

<div class="leftdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Budget Bal:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Budget Rate:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Non-Budget Bal:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">LastPayment Date:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Last Payment Amount:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Security Deposit:</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerlabel">Prev Statment Bal:</label>
</div>

<div class="rightdiv">
  <br/>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$0.00&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$0.00&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$0.00&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">06/27/2012&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$59.25&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$0.00&nbsp;</label>
  <label class="sizedCustomerDataRightlabel">$147.78&nbsp;</label>
</div>

      </div>    
    </fieldset>




</div>

                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"css isn't acting the way I want it to across multiple browsers"_ welcome to the club.

Comment: This might only be useful for me... but if you pasted the generated html, we could mess around with the css more easily.

Comment: @OneTrickPony I removed it, it wasn't doing anything anyhow.

Comment: Can you provide plain HTML code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) with your css?

Comment: I dont know razor. but This might have something to do with what is returned by the Partial function you see how all the customer info is indented in the second example. If you could copy paste what is returned by the function it be easier to diagnose it

Comment: It seemed to work for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk99u.png . Maybe one of your other stylesheets are conflicting? try giving more specific classes or being more specific in your css maybe?

Comment: I think something is wrong inside reset.css, Site.css, or web.css, which are used in page, but not provided. Without them I see no overlapping. Maybe somewhere in there, an outline is added to a div or fieldset, which may result in overlapping?

Comment: The jsfiddle site:  http://jsfiddle.net/TechGuyAlabama/aHkKC/  Hope that helps.

Comment: Remove width:35em in the .sizedCustomerDataLeftLabel

Comment: @MihailGolubev that was it! All I did was remove that. Post that as an answer and I'll give you the check!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the html fragments on the right are contained within an extra div, where the html fragments on the left aren't.  For example, compare how Delivery Address and Balance are defined.  Balance is wrapped in an extra Div.

So, from where I'm sitting, the non-IE browsers are attempting to display the extra divs that IE is ignoring.  Can you define the blocks in the "right-div" section the same as the left?  to me, it looks like it's more about how the content of the right-side groups are defined differently from the left-div groups.

Comment: I have removed the 'extra' divs. I'm not sure that really makes a difference. I have updated my question.

Comment: Looking at the html (thanks for that), canyou use a different style class for the outer divs,, instead of "leftdiv and rightdiv?  It looks like the generated fragments use that as well, and maybe the styles are getting mixed up with the outer left/rightdivs and the ones generated for each containing group?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the .rightDiv so it works with a margin rather than floating it right?

```
.rightDiv {
      position:relative;
      float:left;
      width:49%;
      margin-left:2%;
      text-align:left;
      display:inline;
 }
```

Comment: After looking more at your css in the jsfiddle you created I would definitely stick to using px for all your widths. I thought you must have been using a felxible layout till I saw the 900px wrapper. I'm pretty sure the problem will be down to using %, px and em all in the same css with various bits of padding an margin on the page and main divs.